# Angular 2 radio button events

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, angular

What are those events called in Angular 2 when radio button is selected or unselected.

Something like

```
<input type="radio" (select)="selected()" (unselect)="unselected()" />
```

So when I click one radio button in a group, it will fire `selected()` for the new selection and `unselected()` for the previous selection.

Comment: Radio listing example application http://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-show-radio-input-listing-in-angular-6/

Answer (score 64):

It works,

```
<input type="radio" (change)="handleChange($event)" />
```

But you need code more to judge 'selected' or 'unselected'. 
You may try this in your *.ts file:

```
  export class Comp {

    private _prevSelected: any;

    handleChange(evt) {
      var target = evt.target;
      if (target.checked) {
        doSelected(target);
        this._prevSelected = target;
      } else {
        doUnSelected(this._prevSelected)
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Works well. You can iterate or use switch(target.id) to check the input within input/radio buttons collection. Regards, Carl

Answer (score 5):

The html is like

```
 <div *ngFor = " let displayParameter of displayParameters" >    
    <!-- <li><a href="#">{{displayParameter}}</a></li>     -->
    <!-- <input type="radio"  name="displayParameter"  (change) ="handleChange(event)")>  -->
    <h5><input type="radio" name="radiogroup" (change)="handleChange(displayParameter)" [checked]="(idx === 0)" >{{displayParameter}} </h5>
</div>
```

and code is like

```
 handleChange(evt){ 
            this.displayParameter = evt;
        console.log(evt);
      }
```

Answer (score 5):

It works when you assign the click event to the label, instead of the input.