# Change boolean on (change) event

Tags: angular, typescript, events

I am trying to use a boolean to detect whether a radio button in a form has been checked or not.

**(I left out unneccessary code for both HTML and TS files)**

HTML:

```
<mat-radio-button (change)="toggleEditable($event)" value="overdraft">Overdraft</mat-radio-button>
```

TypeScript:

```
overdraft = false;

toggleEditable(event) {
  if ( event.target.checked ) {
    this.overdraft = true;
  }
}
```

The event is not fired, because when I try to click the radio button and submit the form, `overdraft` is not set to true. **HOWEVER**, if I use a `(click)` event instead of `(change)`, it works fine, **BUT** `(click)` events come with the disadvantage that you have to double-click the radio-buttons for the visual selection to appear, and thus I feel it a neccessity to use `(change)` (see more here: [mat-checkbox does not check if condition is false (only on double click)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067083/mat-checkbox-does-not-check-if-condition-is-false-only-on-double-click/50067108#comment102969092_50067108)).

How do I solve this issue, so that when I click the radio-button, my `(change)` event is fired and `overdraft` is set to true without using the `(click)`-events that come with UI-issues?

**SOLUTION**:

If you want to fetch the actual value of the `mat-radio-button`, you will need to make the following changes:

1) Instead of using `[value]="overdraft"` in HTML, use `value` without square brackets, such as this:
`<mat-radio-button value="overdraft">Overdraft</mat-radio-button>`

2) In your TypeScript code, you can now access the value property from HTML:

```
valueChanged(event: MatRadioChange) {
  console.log(event.value); //will log the value for the button you clicked
}
```

Comment: FYI - Event emitted when the group value changes. Change events are only emitted when the value changes due to user interaction with a radio button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using ngModel?

it might be as simple as:

```
<mat-radio-group  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (change)="valueChanged($event)">
  <mat-radio-button value="overdraft">Overdraft</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="otherValue">Other</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

And in your controller your could have:

```
valueChanged(event) {
    this.overdraft = (event.value ==='overdraft');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great if I choose overdraft, but if I choose otherValue (radio button 2), then I want the value "otherValue" to be set in the valueChanged event. Right now, it always sets this.overdraft to 'overdraft'. Hope it makes sense. Also I dont see the use of selectedValue, as it is never used

Comment: `selectedValue` would be a good to have, if you want to use the selected value somewhere else.

Comment: when you select the 'otherValue' option, that should be the value of the event. Give it a try! =)

Comment: I made it work, but instead of `[value]` in HTML, i just used `value` (without squarebrackets) for the buttons, so in the TypeScript `valueChanged(event)` method, I can access the value from the radio button, e.g. by using `console.log(event.value) //will log the value of chosen button`. I have edited your answer and will approve it once my edit is approved (its under peer review). Thank you VERY much for the help! EDIT: I added my edit/solution to my OP.

Comment: fair enough, I think the square brackets might be phasing out of ng... I have had to remove them from some of my templates as well at times.

Comment: your edit was rejected by a couple of people.... I edited the answer myself to remove the `[]`

Comment: Oh okay, it's weird that I don't receive notification or reason from the people who rejected it, but thanks for letting me know. I accepted your answer - thanks for help

Comment: @thesystem did you remove this accepted answer by accident?

Comment: I have no idea, I dont think I visited this post since 2019. I can accept your answer if you would like?

Comment: if you could, please! I love my points

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you looked at what `console.log(event.target.checked)` gives you back?
2. [Angular 2 radio button events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541106/angular-2-radio-button-events/37541292) try `<input type="radio" "toggleEditable($event)" value="overdraft">Overdraft</input>`
   If it works than, maybe it is a problem with mat-radio-button
3. [Material radio button change event Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362951/material-radio-button-change-event-angular-4) suggests that you need a different type of event:

   `import { MdRadioChange } from '@angular/material';
   ...
   toggleEditable(event: MdRadioChange) {...}`

Comment: Thanks for the help connectedMind, I already found that answer before posting and tried to implement `toggleEditable`, but it didn't quite do the job. I found an answer by tweaking another answer in the post - I edited it into my original post, if you are interested in the solution I found.

Comment: I guess you mean editing the mentioned event type, which was part of my proposition. So I propose: at least give me +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify the value directly in the HTML when `change` event is triggered:

```html
<mat-radio-button (change)="overdraft = !overdraft; display()" [value]="overdraft">Overdraft</mat-radio-button>
```

```
  overdraft = false;
  display() {
    console.log(this.overdraft);
  }
```

The display function is only here for demonstration purpose ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help. This unfortunately didn't quite do the job. I edited my original post with the solution if you are interested.